# ELF unmapped region in a segment

Tags: elf

Below is the output for my readelf -l test

```
Program Headers:                   
Type           Offset   VirtAddr   PhysAddr   FileSiz MemSiz  Flg Align
LOAD           0x000000 0x00008000 0x00008000 0x00148 0x00148 R E 0x8000
LOAD           0x000148 0x00010148 0x00010148 0x00000 0x00004 RW  0x8000
NOTE           0x0000b4 0x000080b4 0x000080b4 0x00024 0x00024 R   0x4
GNU_STACK      0x000000 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000 0x00000 RW  0x4
Section to Segment mapping:
Segment Sections...
00     .note.gnu.build-id .text 
01     .bss 
02     .note.gnu.build-id 
03
```

My question is about the first LOAD segment. It encompasses [8000 - 8148], and is mapped to sections .note and .text. My readelf -S output shows that .note section starts from 80b4, and .text starts from 80d8.  That means Loadable segment contains a region [8000-80b3] which is unmapped to any section, but still will be loaded to memory by loader.

My question is, if there is any harm if I create a new segment which ranges from[80b4-8148] deleting this segment?

Answer (score 1):

> That means Loadable segment contains a region [8000-80b3] which is unmapped to any section, but still will be loaded to memory by loader.

Correct. You will find the `Elf32_Ehdr`, and likely a set of `Elf32_Phdr`s in that segment.

Note: for the main binary, it's actually the kernel that does the loading, and not the dynamic linker. You are not wrong in calling it "loader", but usually people use "loader" for the dynamic linker, and not the "part of the kernel that maps in the main binary".

> My question is, if there is any harm if I create a new segment which ranges from[80b4-8148] deleting this segment?

The segment has to be page-aligned. A segment with `.p_vaddr` that is not page-aligned (as I believe you are proposing) will be rejected by the kernel.

Comment: I also expected that particular segment requires page alignment. But, elf specification only says that  "executable and shared object files must have segment images whose   file offsets and virtual
addresses are congruent, modulo the page size".  It never says each segment has to be page aligned. And, kernel did not reject this binary at all.  What's your take on this?

Comment: If you supply `.p_offset` that is not page-aligned, it will be rounded down, and *whole* page will be `mmap`ed. So look at the `/proc/self/map` for your new binary. You will discover that it's exactly the same as your old binary (and thus your exercise achieved no purpose).

Comment: Yes,  makes sense.  Thanks.